# "ORA-01007: variable not in select list" when no rows are returned by EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql, execute-immediate

I have a procedure which receives as parameter a where clause (i.e. `where col1 = 1`). I am using this clause to search in some tables using an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement and the result to be inserted into a nested table, and than be displayed.

The procedure works fine if any data is found but in case no data is found, then the above error is thrown.

Can someone explain what cause this error, please?

Here is the procedure:

```
create or replace procedure prc_checks(pi_where varchar2) as

    cursor c_tables is
        select object_name, 
        case object_name
            when 'XP_IMPORT_MW' THEN 99999999
            when 'XP_IMPORT_MW_ARCH' THEN 99999998
            else TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(object_name, -8, 8))
        end to_order
        from dba_objects 
        where object_type = 'TABLE' 
        and object_name IN ('XP_IMPORT_MW', 'XP_IMPORT_MW_ARCH') 
        or REGEXP_LIKE (object_name, 'XP_IMPORT_MW_ARCH_201(5|6|7)[0-9]{4}') order by 2 desc;

    type t_result is table of xp_import_mw%rowtype;
    v_result t_result;

    v_sql varchar2(300);

BEGIN  
    for i in c_tables
        loop
            v_sql := 'select * from ' || i.object_name || ' ' || pi_where;
            execute immediate v_sql bulk collect into v_result;

            if v_result.count > 0 
                then 
                    for j in v_result.first .. v_result.last
                    loop
                        dbms_output.put_line(v_result(j).art_nr);
                    end loop;
                    dbms_output.put_line('... the required information was found on table name ' || upper(i.object_name));
                    exit;
            end if;
        end loop;
END prc_checks;
```

Comment: show us the value for pi_where, plus it is assumed that any table in i.object_name has the same rowtype that xp_import_mv

Comment: There is an example given for pi_where: `where col1 = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get this is one of the tables being found by the cursor has fewer columns than `xp_import_mw`. For example:

```
create table xp_import_mw (col1 number, art_nr number, dummy number);
create table xp_import_mw_arch_20160102 (col1 number, art_nr number, dummy number);
create table xp_import_mw_arch_20160101 (col1 number, art_nr number);
insert into xp_import_mw_arch_20160101 values (1, 42);
```

So the main `xp_import_mw` table has three columns but no matching data. One of the old archive tables has one fewer columns.

I added a `dbms_output.put_line(v_sql)` to the procedure to see which table it fails against, then ran it:

```
set serveroutput on
exec prc_checks('where col1 = 1');
```

which got output:

```
select * from XP_IMPORT_MW where col1 = 1
select * from XP_IMPORT_MW_ARCH_20160102 where col1 = 1
select * from XP_IMPORT_MW_ARCH_20160101 where col1 = 1

Error starting at line : 49 in command -
BEGIN prc_checks('where col1 = 1'); END;
Error report -
ORA-01007: variable not in select list
ORA-06512: at "MY_SCHEMA.PRC_CHECKS", line 25
ORA-06512: at line 1
01007. 00000 -  "variable not in select list"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

So the problem isn't that there is no data found; the problem is that there *is* matching data in a table which has the wrong structure.

You could construct the select list based on the `xp_import_mw` table's structure, instead of using `*`; that won't stop it failing, but would at least give you a slightly more helpful error message - in this case `ORA-00904: "DUMMY": invalid identifier` instead of ORA-01007.

You could do a quick and crude check for discrepancies with something like:

```
select table_name, count(column_id) as column_count,
  listagg(column_name, ',') within group (order by column_id) as columns
from dba_tab_columns
where table_name IN ('XP_IMPORT_MW', 'XP_IMPORT_MW_ARCH') 
or REGEXP_LIKE (table_name, 'XP_IMPORT_MW_ARCH_201(5|6|7)[0-9]{4}')
group by table_name
having count(column_id) != (
  select count(column_id) from dba_tab_columns where table_name = 'XP_IMPORT_MW'
);
```

... although if you're using `dba_*` or `all_*` view you should really be including the owner, here and in your procedure.

Comment: Indeed, there was a difference among tables structure. Lazy of me didn't check the number of fields from each table, and, there were differences. The tables have between 649, 651, 653 columns.

Comment: I was trying your last select statement and I received an error related to "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected". Do you have any clue?

Comment: I guess you're on 10g (or earlier), so listagg isn't available... with 650 columns the result would be too long for a SQL string anyway. You could remove that and just do the count, but you seem to already know the counts.